# python beautifulsoup .text None Type

Tags: python, if-statement, text, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I am scraping a website with Beautiful Soup. I am looking for the "prtype" text in a table. My problem is, this column does not always exist.

If the column exists the following code works fine:

```
prtyp = soup.find("dd", attrs={"class":"is_type g"}).text.strip()
```

But, if there is no column with this class I get the following error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

that was one of my tries to get rid off the problem, but prtyp is an str and I get back the whole html tags, or .text doesn't work. of course.

```
prtyp = soup.find("dd", attrs={"class":"is_type g"})
if prtyp is None:
    prtyp = "no type"
else:
    whgtyp.text.strip()
    print("prtype:", prtype)
```

Comment: `try: whgtyp.text.strip()
    print("prtype:", prtype); except AttributeError: prtyp = "no type"`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna extract that string you can do the follow

```
if "prtype" in soup.find("body").text:
    prtyp = soup.find("dd", attrs={"class":"is_type g"})
    if prtyp is None:
       prtyp = "no type"
    else:
       # whgtyp.text.strip() # I don't know what it does
       print("prtype:", prtype)
```

You can check if the string exists in the HTML body, anyway I see that in your find method you are looking for a "dd" tag, if you want to search in a table, it should be in a td tag (if it is a HTML table)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answers. didnt try it yet but found a one line answer:

```
prtyp = soup.find("dd", attrs={"class":"is_type g"}).text.strip() if soup.find("dd", attrs={"class":"is_type g"}) else "no type"
```